# Type constructor for subtracting HList types?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am looking for a type contructor that can subtract one HList type with another.

```
trait Subtract {
  type Aux[Full <: HList, ToSubract <: HList] = ???
}

object SubtractExample {
  type AList = ClassA :: ClassB :: HNil 
  type BList = ClassB :: HNil

  Subtract.Aux[AList, BList] == ClassA :: HNil
}
```

If such constructor doesn't exist, can someone point me to the direction in how to implement one? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `AList` will always contain the elements of `BList` in order (but not necessarily contiguously), you can use `RemoveAll`:

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist.RemoveAll

trait ClassA; trait ClassB

type AList = ClassA :: ClassB :: HNil
type BList = ClassB :: HNil

val remover = RemoveAll[AList, BList]

remover(new ClassA {} :: new ClassB {} :: HNil)
```

This will return a tuple of the removed elements and the leftovers (which is what you want).

This works for your example case, and even if your requirements are slightly different, [the `RemoveAll` implementation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/fe7833e82e3e059e58a5ee102d077483bf58a102/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L1112) would be a good place to start.

As a footnote, while `RemoveAll` *is* a type constructor, in this context it's more relevantly a type class. It also doesn't really make sense to have a type class with no type parameters but an `Aux` (which would normally be defined in the companion object, not the type class itself) with two. I'd suggest looking at the role `Aux` plays in the `RemoveAll` type class as an example of this pattern.